# How to get the username for a custom link

Tags: users

I want to create a link that will change based on the user clicking the link.

The User will be signed in and be accessing their "storefront". I want to have the link be a link to their specific storefront

for example

www.mywebsite.myweb/storefront/USERNAME

where username would change based on the user clicking
I'm fairly new to this so please explain like I know nothing

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
echo 'http://www.mywebsite.myweb/storefront/' . $current_user->user_login;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would I flank this with php open and closers or just put it in plain.

Comment: Depends on your surrounding code you can always prefix both lines with `<?php` and suffix them with `?>`.